# DropDownList To Filter DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a table which contains 4 Columns. What I want to be able to do is to filter this datatable according to the selection of a multiple DropDownList.

How can I delete the rows which don't contain the selection?? I've used SQL to populate the datatable but I don't want to call SQL to filter the datatable?

Heres my code on how I add the datatable and populate the dropdownlists

```
private DataTable LoadDataTable()
{
    //conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DataTest", conn);

    adapter.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();  
    return dt;                                          
}

public void PopulateDDL()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Column1 FROM DataTest", conn);
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader ddlValues;
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DropDownList1.DataSource = ddlValues;
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Column1";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Column1";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    cmd.Connection.Close();            
}
```

Anyway I could go about it?

Comment: which rows you are talking about to delete ?

Comment: The rows which dont contain the Text of the dropdown. So for example in the drop down i select "TV" i want all rows which dont contain "TV" to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can try

```
// Presuming the DataTable has a column named List. 
string expression;
expression = "List != TV";
DataRow[] foundRows;

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = table.Select(expression);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this datable information website](http://www.datatables.net/) and more specifically this jquery extension for datatables ["Yet Another DataTables Column Filter"](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)

The link contains [a live example](http://jsbin.com/esezof/1)

It's the business!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the datatable based on multiple values selection from Multidropdown, you can achieve this by using following code. Let assume your multidropdown contains `asp:CheckboxList` with id `chkMultiSelection`

let's say you have all the data on `System DataTable dt` and that need to filter based on selection of MultiDropDownlist

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
var filterDataTable = new DataTable();
//get all the selection of MultiDropDown and seperated them by comas..
string selectedValues = string.Join(", ", chkMultiSelection.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Text));

//convert your multiselection to array
string[] multiValues = selectedValues.Split(',');

//iterate through them and filter the data based on selection. That will filter the rows which don't contain the selection
foreach (string s in multiValues)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> datarow = default(IEnumerable<DataRow>);
    datarow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ColumnName") == s.Trim());
    if (datarow.Count() > 0)
    {
        filterDataTable = datarow.CopyToDataTable(); 

        //use dataset and store each filter data
        dataSet.Tables.Add(filterDataTable);

    }
}
```